# How to determine if wall can handle TV weight

Tags: hanging, television

I just moved into a new apartment and I’m working through getting settled in. I want to hang a TV over the fireplace (see pic) but I’m not sure if the wall can handle it. The TV and mount weigh 70lbs total. I will screw the mount into studs that are in the wall over the fireplace but I’m not sure how it’s supported around the fireplace.

What should I look for on this wall to make sure this wall can handle the weight?

[image: wall over fireplace]

Comment: Walls don't fall down. Improperly mounted heavy things do.

Comment: Put a mirror there. mounting TVs this high makes is terrible to watch unless you are stood in a bar. A TV really should be around eye-height when you are sat watching. Oh and the glare from the windows will mean you are squinting constantly as well as uncomfortable!!!!

Comment: I want to mirror the previous comment. Do not place the TV over the fireplace. I know it seems to be all the rage these days to put the flat screen TV up there but it is the wrong solution for many reasons. Over time your neck will suffer from staring up to watch it from the couch or easy chair. The TV will suffer from the aging that happens to electronics that are exposed to a high heat environment. Wall mounting loses so much room placement flexibility over using a console with a built on TV mount post.

Comment: Any Flat screen mount I have seen will permit adjustment of the screen angle to a comfortable viewing angle with minimum reflections. I have put in 5 ( the wife likes TV ) any where for a simple tipper to full swivels. 70 # is a safe load for one stud but i think most of mine attach to 2 studs .

Comment: I have a big screen over a piano and love it. I have a "picture frame" around it and get positive comments all the time on how nice it looks and it makes my room feel more like a theater, who ever gave your question a down vote is wrong! Fyi have you noticed where TV's are in hospitals and waiting rooms? The only caution I would give is if you plan on using the fireplace it may shorten the life of the TV due to the heat. I have seen quite a few tv's above actively used wood stove inserts and and even several with just doors. I have installed outlets over mantles for this purpose.

Comment: seriously, please don't put your television over your mantle. It looks horrible. Absolutely horrible. Painting or mirror.

Comment: The TV is going there.  It's a giant room and large TV.  The angle of looking at it won't be an issue.  It if is...I'll remove the 4 screws and put it elsewhere.  And there are no curtains on the windows now, which will be changed...  It is going to be amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you're placing your bolts for the TV mount into to the wall studs, or if it is brick into a secure hole in the brick the weight will be no problem. If you just put the screws into the drywall, it will not be very secure.

Comment: I agree, you may find wood studs to anchor to this is quite common with "finished" walls in the Pacific northwest. Spreading the load across at least 2 studs would be my requirement for support If the sheetrock is glued to the brick you will want the anchors into the brick.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your studs are properly spaced with 16" centers (there abouts), you
should not have a weight issue.  If you have a good flu in your fireplace, you should not have a heat issue either.  Build a fire and test the heat.